# Android Studio "paint brush" icon in front of certain attributes

Tags: android, android-studio, attributes

In the attributes pane, I occasionally see two attributes with the same name, where one attribute has what looks like a "paint brush" icon in front of it (for example, in the screenshot below, the `text` attribute). I've searched but can't find what this means or what the difference is between the attributes.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter some text in the `text` field **with** the *"paint brush"* icon 
then this attribute will be added to the xml:

```
tools:text="989"
```

this attribute, from the `tools` namespace (`xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`), 

is set **for design time**, a value you can see in the preview of the layout and it is not compiled.  
 
If you enter some text in the `text` field **without** the *"paint brush"* icon  
 then this attribute will be added to the xml:

```
android:text="888"
```

this is the attribute that will be compiled in the apk of your app and you will see when you run the app.